# XDMP-PARENTLINK error on Fragment Root with xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am trying to insert a document having a **element** which is a **fragment root**:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

let $doc := 
<doc>
  <frag-root xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="test.xsd"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  </frag-root>            
</doc>

return xdmp:document-insert("/test.xml", $doc)
```

This xquery throws following error:

```
XDMP-PARENTLINK: xdmp:eval(...) -- Invalid parent link node doc("/test.xml")//doc
```

I've found [this email](https://developer.marklogic.com/pipermail/general/2016-August/019310.html) which is kind of the same behavior but he has a `schemaLocation` instead of a `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attribute.
In my case the element `frag-root` is indeed a fragment root. Might this be a similar bug ?

If i change `noNamespaceSchemaLocation` to `schemalocation`, the insertion does not fail, so my guess is the bug is fixed for `schemaLocation`, but not for `noNamespaceSchemaLocation`.

Comment: I would take this up with MarkLogic support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this error to MarkLogic and they filed a bug for it.
Will update as soon as it is fixed.